# Detecting Android hardware damage

Tags: android, hardware, android-bluetooth, android-sensors

I am trying to figure out if there is any callback from the Bluetooth or Magnet sensor's hardware that can give me indication of actual damage to the hardware's, preventing them to work?

There is of course the standard on/off indication, but I am looking for actual damage indication for these hardware components.